# How SCons hardlinks sources in variant directory?

Tags: python, scons

I tested SCons default hardlink behavior.

I am expecting that a modification in the hardlinked file in the variant dir is reflected also in the original file. But this doesn't happen.

Is hardlinking really a default behavior as stated in SCons doc or it is just copying the files in the variant directory ?

**EDIT:**

Details about my implementations/configurations:

I am using VariantDir with one SConscript in the root of the project

Duplicate option is on in VariantDir

No duplicate option in cmd line (default).

I am using my own custom tools. I am using only the program builder from the builders available by default in SCons.

I tried the following flags: hard-soft-copy (the default), soft-hard-copy, hard-copy, soft-copy or copy.

None of them will provide me a real hard link copy.

I expect the following:

When I change a source file in variant dir the change will be reflected in the original file (at the original location) since the file in variant dir is a hard link.

Instead a change in the source file in the variant dir won't be reflected in the original file.

**EDIT 2:**

After running --debug=duplicate I got for each file considered in the dependency cycle a message similar to this:

```
dup: relinking variant 'relative_path_to_file' from 'absolute_path'
```

Comment: This largely depends on the settings in your SConstruct(s), especially the "duplicate" option. Can you give some more details about what you have tried, which commands you are running and what kind of output you get vs expect?

Comment: I added some comments about my implementation.

Comment: Please check whether your OS and python version offer the required "`os.link`" method/attribute for a proper hard link. You can also specify the "`--debug=duplicate`" command line option to check whether SCons tries to create hard/soft links at all, given your current config. Please report back what you see in the output then...

Comment: I made an edit with the output of --debug=duplicate

Comment: And which OS and Python version are you using?

Comment: Windows and python version 2.7.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the corresponding [Python reference docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.link#os.link), the underlying `os.link` method, that SCons tries to find and use internally to create hard links, is not available under Windows. The same holds true for `os.symlink` (symbolic/soft links), so the only remaining option for SCons under Windows is to actually copy the files.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked that afterward and it won't find any link method in os module. Is there an alternative to make this available in Windows ? I saw that python 3 support this on windows...

Comment: The SCons team is currently working on a mixed 2.7.x/3.y version, which will then make this feature available, when actually using Python3. So watch out for the upcoming release...

Comment: Great, thank you, there is also a problem with the time spent for computing the dependencies on a rebuild, is that also considered for the upcoming releases ?

Comment: It may be that you're hit by an improvement of cross-language scanning in one of our latest releases. If you'd like to discuss this further, please come over to our User mailing list at `scons-users@scons.org` (check out http://scons.org/lists.html for how to subscribe).